# Kubuntu 16.04 can't start vsftpd

Tags: vsftpd

In Kubuntu 16.04 I installed but can't start vsftpd, details below, can someone tell me what's wrong?

> $ cat /etc/vsftpd.conf

listen=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

> $ sudo ufw status
>   Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

> $ sudo systemctl status vsftpd

● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-10-16 11:49:13 PDT; 13min ago
  Process: 2419 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 2416 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/vsftpd/empty (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2419 (code=exited, status=2)

Oct 16 11:49:13 Jboat17 systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 16 11:49:13 Jboat17 systemd[1]: Started vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 16 11:49:13 Jboat17 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 16 11:49:13 Jboat17 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 16 11:49:13 Jboat17 systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found a vsftpd.conf here that works:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181436/vsftpd-wont-start

listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem